# Basic NPM usage - install package error

Tags: node.js, package, installation

I want to install a package called `tone` so I can use this code

```
//create a synth and connect it to the master output (your speakers)
var synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster();

//play a middle 'C' for the duration of an 8th note
synth.triggerAttackRelease("C4", "8n");
```

Here's what I've tried so far (as well as completely reinstalling Node):

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\tone-js>npm install tone
C:\Users\HP
`-- tone@0.8.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HP\package.json'
npm WARN HP No description
npm WARN HP No repository field.
npm WARN HP No README data
npm WARN HP No license field.
```

So I'm guessing I need to create a package.json file. I've tried npm init, and it asks for a point of entry, which I don't understand.

I just want to be able to use the code above. I probably need to add a require statement at the top - what should it be please?

I've also tried installing `tone` globally with `npm install tone -g` but don't know how to require the module. I'm also guessing local is better practice.

Also, why when I run `npm install tone` is it looking for package.json at `'C:\Users\HP\package.json'` when I'm in a different folder?

All very confusing! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `npm init`, the entry file it is asking for is the main file of your application. For instance, if the starting point of your application is in `app.js` then your entry file would be `app.js`. By default, it will be set to `index.js` if you don't provide one.

Another trick to using `npm init` is, if you don't want to setup the `package.json` to be specific to your project at this point in time, use the `-f` flag which will force the use of all defaults for your `package.json`.

Without initializing npm in your project you cannot save any npm packages since there is no `package.json` which is mandatory to save installed packages.

Comment: Don't really like your faulty answer to be the "correct" one.
"Without initializing npm in your project you cannot install any npm packages since there will be no `package.json` which is mandatory to install packages" is just plain falls...
It was the whole reason he didn't get it to start with

Comment: @CreasolDev no meaningful project would ever install a dependency without needing to have a reference to it, and to do that you must have a `package.json` pretty cut and dry. Additionally, my answer actually answers the problem, the lack of a properly created `package.json`.

Comment: Ofcourse it wouldn't, but stating that you CAN'T install modules unless you have a package.json file is still faulty, there is no need to create a package.json file to install problems, so it's still not the correct answer

Comment: @CreasolDev there, added the word "save"

Comment: Still a faulty answer to begin with, making the one asking the question confused in the process.
Please refrain from giving faulty answers in the future.

Comment: @CreasolDev This isn't even close to a "faulty" answer.

Comment: Your last statement is just plain lying to the ones reading this. Other people might see your answer as the accepted one and will believe you really can't install modules without a `package.json`. This is just wrong and 100% false. You might have changed it now, but in the future I won't always be there to correct it, so please be honest next time, in stead of trying to make someone follow a "best practice"/"way of working" when it's not mandatory, especially for quick tests / alpha-prototypes

Comment: The amount of upvoted answers has nothing to do with the skills and knowledge of a person, going after them 'personally' is.
I'm not going into this any further, I'm just trying to let you know you should not give people faulty 'answers' and be proud of what you're doing.
Again, keep in mind other people might use your wrong answer as truth and "learning" material.
That's all

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should know when using Node.js and third party modules.

1. The `package.json` file describes your project. It lists all modules you've installed with the `--save` tag (so `npm install --save tone`)
   You should also know that the `package.json` file is used to tell others who the author of the project is, optionally what dependencies it has during development (`devDepenencies`, mainly used for testing modules etc) and NPM uses it when you publish your own NPM package)
2. To use a module, you need to require it and assign it's exported object to a variable (`const Tone = require('tone');`)
3. The entry point is the same file you call `node` on, so if you normally execute `node app.js`, your entry point is `app.js`. It's for NPM to know which file it make public when you've published a module. (Tip: You can now also run `npm start` instead of `node app.js`
4. For quick tests, just executing `npm install note` still allows you to `require('tone');` without having a `package.json`

Comment: Installing Modules using NPM
There is a simple syntax to install any Node.js module −

$ npm install <Module Name>
For example, following is the command to install a famous Node.js web framework module called express −

$ npm install express
Now you can use this module in your js file as following −

var express = require('express');

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with that comment

Comment: Sorry, I got cut off: I'm still confused. It says here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.htm that I can install modules with `$ npm install <Module Name>

Now you can use this module in your js file as following −

var express = require('express');`

(re point 4 - is express a mode of installation or another package?)

The article says to use --save when creating a module but I don't really want to create anything complex - just to play with some ideas. Why can't I just use `npm install tone` like it says on the package page? Sorry to be dense...

Comment: @Robin I'm not sure why you haven't followed the suggestions in my answer.

Comment: @peteb - It's because now I have two apparently different approaches and I don't know which is correct - do I still need to use --save if I follow your way? Do I need to init before I install? I don't have the overview yet...

Comment: @Robin yes, you do, you always do. If you don't know then theres not way to resolve `require('tone');`, the `tone` is part of your `dependencies` array in your `package.json` which will only exist once you add it to your `package.json`. My answer will create your `package.json` in the directory which you call `npm init -f`. Then simply install your packages as needed and required them as you'd like. Its important to note, you need the `--save` flag in order to do this. That is the most important part of installing your packages.

Comment: @Robin, like I said in point 4 of my answer, you can just run `npm install tone` in your terminal and in your nodejs app state `var Tone = require('tone');` at the top

Comment: @peteb and @CreasolDev are you giving me conflicting advice or am I just not understanding? I ran `npm init -f` followed by `npm install tone` and it worked - no `--save` . Doing `npm install tone` without init caused the original problem. So under what circumstances is `--save` used and not used please?

Comment: @Robin the lack of `--save` means that you have no need to know that it was installed. In most scenarios you wouldn't do this. `--save` signals to `npm install` to install the package and then to save the package as a dependency in your package.json. This would be a big problem if the code ever needs to be run on another machine, also you'd have no way to resolve your package version.

Comment: so `--save` simply updates the package.json to show the dependency?

Comment: @Robin --save should be used when you would like to save the dependency to the `package.json` as a normal dependency. Like I stated in my answer, there is also this thing called `devDependencies` for testing modules etc. You can 'save' to the development dependencies with `--save-dev`.
If you're omitting the `--save` and just running `npm install <Module>` it's still installing, just not saving for the person to work with your project after you ;)

Comment: @robin, Yes, `--save` only saves that version of the module to `package.json` as a dependency